# Why isn't the type() function working here?

Tags: python

I am learning Python, and I was trying to see if functions behave as I expected them to. However, I ran across an issue:

```
import numpy as np

def test():
     return np.array([1, 2, 3])

type(test())
```

I would expect the output to be `numpy.ndarray`. However, I get nothing when I run this script.

I have tried different things instead of the type function; for example, `print(test())` worked as expected. But for some reason the type function doesn't seem to work. Could you please enlightment me as to why? Thanks!

Comment: The result of expressions is only automatically printed in Python's interactive mode.  In a script, you have to explicitly `print()` values.

Comment: Make sure to click the check next to the answer that solves your problem the best (and also explains it the best) to help other on stack overflow and to award the person that helped you with that sweet, sweet reputation!

Comment: @FourInchKnife Yup, done! I appreciate the help a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. You have to print the output
2. There are 2 different cases:

```py
import numpy as np

def test():
     return np.array([1, 2, 3])

print(type(test))
print(type(test()))
```

first will print "class 'function'" the actual type of test

second (your case) will actually call the function (because you wrote it wih (), so test() ) and thus the return will be evaluated, and type will return the type of the result, which will be here "class 'numpy.ndarray'"

Comment: @Blue , No problem. Consider accepting an answer if it was most helpful. Also, although nice, it is not necessary to thank in comments, yse them if you need help with an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to print the output of `test` to be able to see it. Try this:

```
import numpy as np

def test():
     return np.array([1, 2, 3])

print(type(test()))
```

Edit: In Python's interactive console, you don't need to print things to be able to see their output, so that may have tripped you up a bit :|